# Integrating under special cases

Tags: integration

While solving the governing equation for my research topic, I encountered this problem and solved it in a different way but later on I saw the same problem together with the answer in a journal in which I don't have **any idea** of how to go about it.

Integrate 
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{L} cos \dfrac{2 \pi x}{L}\sin \dfrac{m \pi x}{L} \sin \dfrac{k \pi x}{L} dx 
\end{equation}

Answer:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} \dfrac{-mL}{4}, & if \hspace{0.5cm} m\pm k=odd \\ 0, & if \hspace{0.5cm} m \pm k=even \end{cases}
\end{equation}

If the answer provided above is wrong, I would like to know the correct answer.

Comment: The given answer for $m\pm k$ odd cannot be correct because it must be symmetric in $m$ and $k$

Comment: Thanks. How do I go about it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{L} cos \dfrac{2 \pi x}{L}\sin \dfrac{m \pi x}{L} \sin \dfrac{k \pi x}{L} dx =\dfrac{L}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} cos(2x)\sin(mx)\sin(kx)dx$

$ = \dfrac{L}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}[cos(m-k+2)x+cos(m-k-2)x-cos(m+k+2)x-cos(m+k-2)x]dx$

$\dfrac{L}{4\pi}[\dfrac{sin(m-k+2)x}{m-k+2}+\dfrac{sin(m-k-2)x}{m-k-2}-\dfrac{sin(m+k+2)x}{m+k+2}-\dfrac{sin(m+k-2)x}{m+k-2}]$ with limits $0$ to $\pi$.

$\implies$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} \dfrac{L}{4}, & if \hspace{0.5cm} m- k=\pm2 \\ \dfrac{-L}{4}, & if \hspace{0.5cm} m+ k=\pm2 \\ 0, &  \hspace{0.5cm} else \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one question though, I didn't get how the answer became (L/4) and (-L/4) after taking the limit from 0 to $\pi$. I think the whole equation turns to zero at $\pi$ with that condition. I need more clarifications please

Comment: When you replace the limit $\pi$, one of the four terms goes to $\dfrac{0}{0}$ form corresponding to the value of $m \pm k$. Applying L- hospital rule gives you answer $\pi$ for that individual term, and remaining three terms will be zero. Depending on which of the four terms is going to be $\dfrac{0}{0}$, you'll get $\pm \pi$